# Upload and run a big file once to file1.py and run it multiple times in file2.py

Tags: python, bigdata, rdflib

I want to load a big file to a python script once (which is taking time) but I want to avoid loading that file multiple times when running that script multiple times.

For example, I have file1.py which is loading the big file and then in file2.py I am importing that big file. I want to load the big file once into file1.py while running the file2.py multiple times.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to combine the functionalities of the two scripts within a third script.

Example `file3.py`

```
from file1 import upload, load_file, process_data #just an example
from file2 import process_more_data

if not exist(big_file): #implement a function that checks if the file has been uploaded already
    upload(big_file)
data = load_file(big_file)
a = process_data(data)
b = process_more_data(data)
```

Reading at the code added by the op as a comment, it appears that the two scripts can indeed be combined together quite easily:

The following code ca go in the same file.

```
import rdflib

rdffile3="C:/Users/aa/Desktop/YOLO/object-detection-opencv-master/yago_taxonomy-v1.1.ttl"
g3=rdflib.ConjunctiveGraph()
g4=g3.parse(rdffile3, format="turtle")

result = Mapping_function(g4)
```

Comment: I did the same when I am running file3.py its again running file1.py and file2.py. (because they are linked to file3).I want to avoid running file1.py (which uploading big file). thanks

Comment: It's hard to answer without knowing the code of file1.py Can you share your code?

Comment: These are the codes for file1.py and file2.py:
file1.py
import rdflib
#this a big file which is YAGO (Ontology) taxonomy file
rdffile3="C:/Users/aa/Desktop/YOLO/object-detection-opencv-master/yago_taxonomy-v1.1.ttl"
g3=rdflib.ConjunctiveGraph()
g4=g3.parse(rdffile3, format="turtle")

file2.py
from YAGO_texonomy import g4


def Mapping_function(g4):
    #work on g4

Mapping_function(g4)

Comment: @ShahiDost I have modified my answer. You just need to implement a function that checks if the file is already there or not. If it is there, you don't need to upload it again.